# View image in another ImageView when clicked on it

Tags: java, android

I have a profile section in my app with a profile picture in it. When clicked on the profile picture it should be displayed in another activity with large image view like LinkedIn or Facebook. How to do it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to pass information between activities on Android is using Intents. So something like the following would allow you to pass the image URL or path to the Activity which shows the larger view:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), LargeImageActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("IMAGE_PATH", imagePath);
startActivity(intent);
```

The above could be called by an onClickListener on your smaller image view to achieve the result you're after.

See this Android developer doc for more info on Intents:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html